# Forwarding Application and Services Logs using nxlog

Tags: windows-server-2008, syslog, windows-event-log, nxlog

Using nxlog 'im_mseventlog' module I'm able to forward all Windows Logs (Application, Security, System... ) logs to the remote syslog server. But I'm not able to forward eventlogs present under 'Application and Service Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Logs' to the syslog server using nxlog. Is there any module to forward those event logs

Answer (score 2):

Got solution for forwarding 'Application and Service Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Logs' using nxlog.

Need to add the following Query inside the 'im_msvistalog' module

```
Query   <QueryList>  \
                <Query Id="0">  \
                <Select Path="System">*</Select> \
            <Select Path="Application">*</Select>  \
            <Select Path="Security">*</Select> \
            <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-Windows Firewall With Advanced Security/Firewall">*</Select> \
            </Query> \
        </QueryList>\
```

This would forward the windows firewall with advanced security log along with other eventlogs. Thanks for the answers and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no other EventLog modules for nxlog.
It could be possible that Enterprise version is more capable in this field than Community version I assume your are using.

Maybe not directly answering your question but you can try other log shipper ... I recommend https://github.com/Cimpress-MCP/TimberWinR, it uses MS's LogParser to access EventLog.